# what is exactly the reason of halting

Tags: algorithm, theory, computation-theory, halting-problem

The halting problem states that given an input and a program, there is no 
algorithm that can decide weather the program will halt. This renders this problem undecidable.
My misunderstanding of the halting problem is that, can't we 
just create another program that could check if the program has 
infinite loops. I just mean that it may be possible to check the cases 
where a loop will not stop and based on that decides if the program will halt
or not. Please could you let me know what's wrong of my understanding of this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you know, the proof of the halting problem is pretty trivial.
Let's assume you have a program that tells you whether a given program will halt or not (forget about inputs for simplicity).  Let's call this program doesHalt(program).
Let's now write a new program called

```
myHalt() 
  if doesHalt(myHalt):
     infinite loop
  else 
     return
```

What should be the return value of

```
doesHalt(myHalt)
```

To answer your specific question: how does your program examining loops will know whether a given loop halt or not?
Does the loop

```
for (i = 1; i += 10; ) {
   if (i == 7) break;
}
```

loop forever or not?  How did your program figure that out?

Comment: Great, you mean the program itself which examines the myHalt program may not halt! 
I see, I don't think my program would ever be able to evaluate the the 7th i. 
Thanks a lot

Comment: no, in this proof we take a alleged working program doesHalt() and show that we can use it to construct a new program which will cause a logical paradox/contradiction and thus prove our assumption that doesHalt exists wrong.